# internal method not found error while using spring-cloud-gcp-pub-sub-stream-binder in spring boot 2.6.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to integrate spring-cloud-gcp-pub-sub-stream-binder in my spring boot project to consume events from gcp pub sub topic and getting the below error while running the project.

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    com.google.cloud.spring.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.provisionConsumerDestination(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:81)

The following method did not exist:

    'boolean com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName.isParsableFrom(java.lang.String)'

The calling method's class, com.google.cloud.spring.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/Users/pranay.garg/.m2/repository/com/google/cloud/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder/3.3.0/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-3.3.0.jar!/com/google/cloud/spring/stream/binder/pubsub/provisioning/PubSubChannelProvisioner.class

The called method's class, com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/pranay.garg/.m2/repository/com/google/api/grpc/proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1/1.84.0/proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1-1.84.0.jar!/com/google/pubsub/v1/TopicName.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName: file:/Users/pranay.garg/.m2/repository/com/google/api/grpc/proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1/1.84.0/proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1-1.84.0.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes com.google.cloud.spring.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner and com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName
```

I am using spring boot v2.6.1
and my dependencyManagement

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

and my related dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency
```

I think it's a version compatibility issue where PubSubChannelProvisioner is trying to call a method in TopicName which is not present but I am not able to figure out the solution for this.
Let me know if you need any other information which might have been missed.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised on issue on spring-cloud-gcp github repo and got the issue resolved. Turns out it was due to a version conflict in libraries-bom dependency management version [solution](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1236)

Answer (score 1):

I believe GCP Adapter in s-c-function is using proto-google-cloud-pubsub v1.0.0 and in your case you are using 1.84. So perhaps we need to update.
Feel free to raise an issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues